# throw not found exception if pubsub topic is not available

Tags: spring, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using spring boot to interact with pubsub topic.

My config class for this connection look like this:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.core.PubSubTemplate;
import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.core.publisher.PubSubPublisherTemplate;
import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.support.PublisherFactory;
import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.support.converter.SimplePubSubMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;
import org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;
import org.springframework.util.concurrent.SettableListenableFuture;

import com.google.api.core.ApiFuture;
import com.google.api.core.ApiFutureCallback;
import com.google.api.core.ApiFutures;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage;

public abstract class PubSubPublisher {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PubSubPublisher.class);

    private final PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate;


    protected PubSubPublisher(PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate) {
        this.pubSubTemplate = pubSubTemplate;
    }

    protected abstract String topic(String topicName);

    public  ListenableFuture<String> publish(String topicName, String message) {
        LOGGER.info("Publishing to topic [{}]. Message: [{}]", topicName, message);
        return pubSubTemplate.publish(topicName, message);
    }

}
```

And I am calling this at my service, like this:

```
publisher.publish(topic-name, payload);
```

This publish method is async one, which always pass on did not wait for acknowldgrment. I make add get after publish for wait until it get the response from pubsub.

But I wanted to know if in case my topic is not already present and i try to push some message, it should throw some error like resource not found, considering using default async method only.

Might be implementing the callback would help but i am unable to do that in my code. And the current override publish method which use callback is just throwing the WARN not exception i wanted that to be exception. that is the reason i wanted to implement the callback.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if Topic already present

```
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

project_id = "projectname"
topic_name = "unknowTopic"

publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_name)
try:
    response = publisher.get_topic(topic_path)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

This returns the error as

```
404 Resource not found (resource=unknowTopic).
```